# using smartStore in an iOS application which is integrated with salesforce mobile-sdk iOS

Tags: ios, salesforce-ios-sdk

How to develope offline capability for an iOS application using smartStore framework ?

so far in our application we have implemented all modules using direct queries to salesforce using **SFRestApi** with the delegate methods such as

```
// Send a request factory message to the singleton SFRestAPI instance
let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance.requestForQuery("SELECT Name FROM User LIMIT 10")    
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance.send(request,delegate:self)
```

Now we want to store data in device using **smartStore**. How do we proceed? I'm open to all suggestions.
Thanks in advance.